# Hide audiolinks from public

Tags: html, google-chrome, download, html5-audio

I'm creating a mediaplayer in my website using html5 audio.

I'm struggling with not allowing the users to download my audiofile. The problem is not in my webpage, as I can simply use the controlslist to disable download. The problem is, if someone gets the link to the source on my server, and opens it in a new tab in chrome, then they have a download-button in the chrome audioplayer.

How can I remove this option? I can not allow the users to download the audiofiles.

**Edit:**

Or maybe the best way to go around this is to use the javascript Audio-class? Then I won't expose the sourceurl. What do you think? Any downsides/upsides choosing one of them?

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Well, I'm asking, so I don't know. I just figured it has to be some way to do it? Is it not?

Comment: The moment you make the audio url available for the browser to load and consume, it's exposed (by definition)..

Comment: @K3N Ok, thanks for the info 